# mysql2: error on reading inital communication packets

Tags: mysql, ruby, ssh

following setup: ruby script on raspbian, external database (connection with ssh and msyql2).
Problem: Gateway and port generation is OK, but trying to establish a mysql connection fails everytime with "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0".
Stackoverflowing and google tips didn't help this far, so here am I. My code below:

```
gateway = Net::SSH::Gateway.new('external_server', 'username', {:password => 'password', :port => '22'})
port = gateway.open("127.0.0.1", 3306, 3307)
#if gateway and port generation successful
  database = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "127.0.0.1", :port => port, :username => 'user_extern', :password => 'password_extern', :database => 'database_extern')
  #do some stuff with database.query("")
database.close
gateway.close(port)
```

and the "Mysql2::Client.new" fails with  described error.
Already tried: 
- restart
- unbind 127.0.0.1
- bind to 0.0.0.0
- took "localhost"
- changed hosts.allow to ALL

Maybe you can add something to that list which I overlooked or I should have a try with?
(Note: if/else and exception handling have been removed for the sake of readability)

Thanks in advance!
/Devyn

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally have the solution. Coding was OK, another provider worked fine. So not always it is wrong code. Finally, somebody else was to blame!
Have a nice day,
Devyn